# Adding a character to every row in a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table in which I inserted a large batch of records. All these records have a certain column in which one character is missing: they're missing a slash `/` at the beginning. Is there a way to add this character to the beginning of this column in every row, using purely SQL?

It wouldn't be a problem in PHP, but I'd like to know a solution in SQL. I know of the SQL UPDATE statement, of course, but I'm not sure how to let it rely on the current value. The best I can come up with is using a subquery:

```
UPDATE the_table t 
SET the_column = 
    CONCAT('/', SELECT the_column FROM the_table WHERE id=t.id)
```

Would this work, and is this the easiest solution? I'm on MySQL 5.5.31.

Comment: Do you have records in your table that you don't want to update? or do all of them need to be updated?

Comment: @DavidFaber I want to update all, I just forgot to accept an answer ;-) sorry!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply use this:

```
UPDATE the_table t 
SET the_column = 
    CONCAT('/', the_column )
```

Answer (score 2):

Your version might work.  But you really just want to do:

```
UPDATE the_table t 
    SET the_column = CONCAT('/', the_column)
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this ?

```
UPDATE t SET column = Concat('/', column);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
UPDATE table t SET column = CONCAT('/', column)
```